# Ubuntu won't shut down!

Tags: shutdown, restart

I am using asus k40IE laptop and want to install Ubuntu 16.04 or newer versions.The laptop is quite old. But Ubuntu won't shut down (hants at showing ubuntu logo) at all. Shutdown also gets stuck with 18.04 and 18.10. Only Ubuntu 14. Only no issue when I am using 14.04. When I enable nvidia graphics, pc would shut down but won't get past login screen each time I try to login.
I really want to enjoy newer Ubuntu versions. Is there any solve...

Comment: The last line of /var/log/syslog when you brute-force off the system should give you a hint of what it was doing at that time, often running one of the scripts in `/etc/rc0.d`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on my Dell 1501.  I had no problem in shutdown/poweroff/reboot on i386 Kubuntu 14.04.   I could not shutdown/poweroff/reboot it on AMD64 Kubuntu 18.04.1 LTS any more.

Adding boot options do not work.

To work around it, I use the old kernel.  I downloaded and installed the 4.4.0-141 image manually.

```
root@dell1501:~# dpkg -l linux* | grep -v none
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
||/ Name                                   Version              Architecture Description
+++-======================================-====================-============-===============================================================
ii  linux-base                             4.5ubuntu1           all          Linux image base package
ii  linux-firmware                         1.173.2              all          Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
ii  linux-generic                          4.15.0.42.44         amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-42                4.15.0-42.45         all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.15.0
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-42-generic        4.15.0-42.45         amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-141                4.4.0-141.167        all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.4.0
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-141-generic        4.4.0-141.167        amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                  4.15.0.42.44         amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-42-generic          4.15.0-42.45         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic          4.4.0-141.167        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-141-generic    4.4.0-141.167        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                    4.15.0.42.44         amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64                   4.15.0-42.45         amd64        Linux Kernel Headers for development
ii  linux-modules-4.15.0-42-generic        4.15.0-42.45         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-42-generic  4.15.0-42.45         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-sound-base                       1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5 all          base package for ALSA and OSS sound systems
```

I kept the new kernel around just in case we need it.  To trick grub to use the older kernel as default, I hard linked the older vmlinuz and initrd.img to a new version say 9.1.1.

Now my Dell 1501 boots up on the 4.4.0 kernel to work around the issue.

```
uname -a
Linux dell1501 4.4.0-141-generic #167-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 5 10:40:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

If ubuntu has a fix, please wake me up.

Thanks.

Comment: Can we see how you install the kernel?